# Laravel - Dynamic Input Field Failed to Submit without Displaying any Error

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have been battling with this issue for some days now. I have a project on Laravel-5.8

I have two model classes

AppraisalGoal

```
protected $fillable = [
          'goal_type_id',
          'appraisal_identity_id',
          'employee_id',
          'company_id',
          'is_published',
          'is_approved',
          'weighted_score',
          'employee_comment',
          'line_manager_comment',
          'goal_title',
          'start_date',
          'end_date',
          'created_by',
          'created_at',
          'updated_by',
          'updated_at',
          'is_active'
      ];
```

AppraisalGoalDetail

```
protected $fillable = [
          'name',
          'company_id',
          'appraisal_goal_id',
          'kpi_description',
          'appraisal_doc',
          'activity',
          'created_by',
          'created_at',
          'updated_by',
          'updated_at',
          'is_active'
      ];
```

Appraisal Goal is the main model

StoreAppraisalGoalRequest

```
class StoreAppraisalGoalRequest extends FormRequest
{
 public function rules()
 {
return [
    'goal_title'                => 'required|min:5|max:100',   
    'goal_type_id'              => 'required',
    'weighted_score'            => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:500',

    'start_date'                => 'required',
    'end_date'                  => 'required|after_or_equal:start_date',
    'appraisal_goal_id'         => 'required',
    'kpi_description'           => 'required|max:300',
    'activity'                  => 'required|max:300',
 ];
 }
}
```

Controller

```
public function create()
{
$userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

$identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();

$goaltypes   =       AppraisalGoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
 $categories = AppraisalGoalType::with('children')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.create')
        ->with('goaltypes', $goaltypes)
        ->with('categories', $categories)
        ->with('identities', $identities);
}

public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{
 $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
$endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
$userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
$appraisal_identity_id = AppraisalIdentity::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current',1)->value('id');
try {
    $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
    $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
    $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $appraisal_identity_id;
    $goal->employee_id              = $request->employee_id;
    $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
    $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;
    $goal->start_date               = $startDate;
    $goal->end_date                 = $endDate;
    $goal->company_id               = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $goal->created_by               = Auth::user()->id;
    $goal->created_at               = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $goal->is_active                = 1;
    $goal->save();

    foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
        $goaldetail = new AppraisalGoalDetail();
        $goaldetail->kpi_description            = $request->kpi_description[$key];
        $goaldetail->appraisal_doc              = $request->application_doc[$key];
        $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];
        $goaldetail->appraisal_goal_id          = $goal->id;
        $goaldetail->company_id                 = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $goaldetail->created_by                 = Auth::user()->id;
        $goaldetail->created_at                 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $goaldetail->is_active                  = 1;
        $goaldetail->save();
     }
        Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Goal is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
} catch (Exception $exception) {
        Session::flash('danger', 'Appraisal Goal creation failed!');
        return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
}
}
```

create.blade

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
         <div class="card card-secondary">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Creating My 3 + 1 Goals: <b>{{$identities->appraisal_name}}</b></h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
          <form  method="POST" action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.store')}}">
          @csrf
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
                <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                  <option disabled="disabled" value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                    @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endunless
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                  @endunless
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Title:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="goal_title" placeholder="Enter goal title here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Goal Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="goal_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Goal Description here ..."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Activity<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">KPI Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Attachment</th>
                            <th scope="col"><a class="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi" ></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="appraisal_doc[]" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>


                    </table>
        </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Weight:</label>
              <input  type="number" name="weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Start Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="start_date"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> End Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="end_date"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           
       
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
   </div>
   <!--/.col (left) -->
  </div>
```

javascript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
   var isHod = {{ Auth::user()->is_hod == 0 ? 0 : 1 }};
    var numRows = $('.activity').length

    if (isHod || (!isHod && numRows<3)) {
        addRow();
    }
        });

        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
' <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>\n' +
'   <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi_description" ></td>\n' +
' <td><div class="custom-file"><input type="file" name="appraisal_doc[]" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile"><label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label></div></td>\n' +
'  <td><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
'    </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
       addRemoveListener();
    });

function addRemoveListener() {
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
        var l =$('tbody tr').length;
        if(l==1){
            alert('you cant delete last one')
        }else{

            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        }

    });
  }

</script>
```

When I click on submit button, it did not save any record but redirected to the index page. No error indicated, even in the Browser Network.

Then, I added this before the  try{} in the store function of the controller:

> $data = $request->all(); print_r($data); exit;

and I got this result:

> Array ( [_token] => KbnpT9MAFywHJBfVoWllKvr2ELSsRNZmWM4B5Eui [goal_type_id] => 2 [appraisal_identity_id] => 8 [goal_title] => goal title1 [goal_description] => [activity] => Array ( [0] => activity2 [1] => activity3 ) [kpi_description] => Array ( [0] => kpi description2 [1] => kpi description3 ) [weighted_score] => 20 [start_date] => 2020-02-03 [end_date] => 2020-02-29 )

But when I added

> print_r($goal); exit;

after

> $goal->save();

There was no result.

How do I get this sorted out?

Thank you.

Comment: inside `catch` statement, you can look the exception with `dd($exception->getMessage());`

Comment: @M.FahmiUlulAzmi - Thanks a lot. You solved the problem. I observed that there was a required field : employee_comment.   Thanks

Comment: @mikefolu Can you get Fahmi to submit an answer, and accept it? Makes for a cleaner Q&A page, in case someone else runs into a similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes some dev using try catch statement but forget to look whats wrong while the code thrown an exception. so lets change your catch statement to this for figure out whats wrong.

```
}catch (Exception $exception) {
        dd($exception->getMessage());
        Session::flash('danger', 'Appraisal Goal creation failed!');
        return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
}
```